# Display Google Map in extension popup

Tags: google-maps, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to display (and work with) a Google Maps API map in an extension popup.  I added https://maps.googleapis.com and https://maps.gstatic.com/ to the content_security_policy, but apparently Maps uses inline evals (!) so this just throws errors.

I also tried to create a map page in my extension and pull it in as an iframe but it appears the Maps API detects that and just shows an image.

Any hints how to get a Google Maps API map to show in a popup?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google has released a sandboxing mechanism for dealing with "unsafe" JS.  See it here: http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/trunk/sandboxingEval.html

It works in Chrome Beta and at least in earlier coding seems to cover what I need.

Kinda sad you need to sandbox Google's own code, but there it is.

Answer (score 1):

We are facing the same issue. Here's what we found out.

If you are using manifest version 2, this issue cannot be fixed. See Bug raised at google maps api issues: [Bug 4201](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/detail?id=4201&can=5&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Introduced%20Fixed%20Summary%20Stars%20ApiType%20Internal)

To solve this in our app, we are still using manifest version 1, and adding 'unsafe-eval' in  script-src in the Content security policy string.

Comment: Ayup.  I found that bug and voted for it.  I also fell back to manifest version 1 too.

Comment: FYI The Chrome Webstore won't accept manifest version 1 starting in mid August :(

Answer (score 0):

Even i'm facing the same issue. My chrome extension was mainly based on google maps.
I had functionality to show different kind of location with custom markers and it was going to be released in next few weeks. Now this has been a major blocker....